# How can I create a variable that is incremental in a bat file?

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I am wanting to make a bat file that when I input my data, it saves a variable to another bat file. I am able to do so, but the problem is that I want to use the same variable for other data.

So is it possible to have %var%=Green and then have the bat file realize that %var% is already in use and instead uses %var1% so that it can %var1%=Red? I have tried for loops and if statements but I don't think that I am using them the right way.

Any help appreciated!

This is what I'm using right now

```
If Exist %var% (
set /a variable=!variable!+1)
set /p var=Enter Card Number: 
set /p val=Enter Amount: 
set /p fname=Enter First Name: 
set /p lname=Enter Last Name: 
set /p cbal=Enter Current Balance:
```

Edit:
so if %var% exists it should create %var1% and then if %var1% exists create %var2% and so on and so forth. Everything entered above though should be linked together. So when i type in the card number, the first name and last name along with current balance displays properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not well defined but this solves what you have asked:

```
if not defined var (
   set var=green
  ) else (
   set var1=red
)
```

Comment: Okay i see that would work, but i am wanting to add more variables through the script. I'm wanting to create a minor database if that makes sense.

Comment: Open a new question and describe what you are after, with examples.

Comment: I have posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793087/create-a-database-within-a-bat-file