# Why are my variables not expanding properly

Tags: variables, batch-file, expansion

I am working on a database using a bat file an my variables are not expanding the right way.

**Edit:**

I have tried the above and have had no such luck.

This is all of the code necessary to show:

```
set n=0

:1
echo.
set /p fname=Enter First Name: 
set /p lname=Enter Last Name: 
set /p val%n%=Enter E-mail: 
set /p num%n%=Enter Phone Number: 
set /p var%n%=Enter Service Number:
set /p dvice%n%=Enter Device: 
set /p dserv%n%=Enter Date Serviced: 
set /p summ%n%=Enter Summary of Service: 
@echo set var%n%=!var%n%! > "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat"
@echo set val%n%=!val%n%! >> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat"
@echo set fname=%fname% >> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat"
@echo set lname=%lname% >> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat"
@echo set dvice%n%=!dvice%n%! >> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat"
@echo set dserv%n%=!dserv%n%! >> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat"
@echo set summ%n%=!summ%n%! >> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat"
@echo set num%n%=!num%n%! >> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat"
@echo set n=%n% >> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat"
echo.
echo The data has been stored!
echo.
pause > nul
goto start

:2
echo.
echo LAST NAME IS CASE SENSITIVE!
set /p lname=Please enter last name: 
echo.
if /i not exist "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat" (goto Error)
call "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat"
echo First Name: %fname%    
echo Last Name: %lname%
echo Device: !%dvice%%n%!   
echo Date of Service: !dserv%n%!
echo.
echo E-Mail: !val%n%!
echo Phone: !num%n%!
echo.
echo Summary:
echo.
echo !summ%n%!
echo.
pause > nul
goto start
```

This is all I have to work with. The %lname%.bat stores variables as var0="value of variable" The problem is that it is not reading var0. It reads !var 0!.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to diagnose the problem. Perhaps the problem is the values were never set, or else the values were lost due to ENDLOCAL or some other similar reason. Try `set` with  no arguments to see all defined variables.

Comment: I actually removed the code because it made the post long. The variables were set as !var%n%! And were stored correctly. Just aren't able to be read.

Comment: I strongly suggest you follow my suggestion and put the `set` command (without arguments) at the end of your code to list all currently defined variables. I am confident you will see that your variables are no longer defined. The problem is in earlier code that you are not showing, as Magoo has stated in his answer.

Comment: set shows the variables that way that I have want them to.var%n%="service number" All are working, it is the reading that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a n=0
:: call "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat"
:start
call :plname
echo First Name: %fname%    
echo Last Name: %lname%
echo Device: !%dvice%%n%!   
echo Date of Service: !dserv%n%!
echo.
echo E-Mail: !val%n%!
echo Phone: !num%n%!
echo.
echo Summary:
echo.
echo !summ%n%!
echo.
SET /a n+=1
IF %n% lss 2 goto START

GOTO :EOF

:plname
SET "fname=First name read"
SET "lname=Last name read"
SET "dvice0=Device zero"   
SET "dvice1=Device one"   
SET "dserv0=Date zero"   
SET "dserv1=Date one"   
SET "val0=Email zero"   
SET "val1=Email one"   
SET "num0=Phone zero"   
SET "num1=Phone one"   
SET "summ0=Summary zero"   
SET "summ1=Summary one"   
GOTO :EOF
```

This batch proves that your code does work. The problem is with your `%lname%.bat` which you haven't posted. Surely you don't set up a different `%lname%.bat` for each customer?

No harm in posting some real sample data - just change the names to protect the guilty. Modify the real names to "Brown" or "Green" or "Robinson." No-one appears to use those names any more - they're obviously fake.

Comment: +1, But I personally know a Brown family that might take exception to your last sentence! Clark Kent, Lois Lane, John Doe, Jane Doe, etc. might be better bets.

Comment: I will add the code later tonight. %lname%.bat is for each individual customer. The data will have multiple service numbers. The key in this is to have one person with several service numbers and summaries along the road. This will be a mini database that i can edit quickly.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the script, a new instance of cmd is running. The variables set are only available to that instance.

```
set filepath=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\My Personal Files\Computer Refresh\Database\%lname%.bat
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%filepath%) do %%a
```

This will loop through each line of `%lname%.bat` and run that line as a command - if all of the lines in `%lname%.bat` are those set commands, this should work.

Comment: It did not work. I edited my code above. I'm not sure if I entered it correctly or not.